# Show a UITabBar when some condition is true

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm currently a beginner to the swift programming language and Xcode as a whole and I am trying to make a basic application.

What I am trying to achieve is for my ViewController to show a UITabBar after I've performed an check to make sure a condition is true.

I firstly have a UITableViewController which checks appends all titles from a table on my database and stores them in an array.

Then, when I click on a cell, a new controller opens which using the name from the array's indexPath and uses that as the views header.

I then do a check to see if the first item in the array is equal to the views title, and this is where I need help.

I want to create a tab bar (like seen in the picture) to display only if the title is equal to the first entry in my array. I've done the check this check:

```
if (institutionConnected + " University" == (self.navigationItem.title!)) {
        print("You are connected to this institution")
        print("This is the first entry")
}
```

> institutionConnected is a string variable which I assign the first item of the array too

I'm a little unsure from here how to create a tab bar as well as it's positioning so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Also, obviously on the other views which will not have the tab bar, there will be a bit of empty space where the tab bar will be hidden so any ideas on how to make my tableView fill the page to avoid empty space?

[This is the view with the tab bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PYl8W.png)  
 
[Table view which when clicked opens the view with the tab bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5bzk0.png)

I hope i've explained but please ask for more information if needed!

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly,

I think you should create a TabBarViewController first, then connect the TabBarViewController with your TableViewController.

In your TableViewController, you can use below function to hide or show your tab bar

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    self.tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = true
}
```